# Writing values to another table from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a database with two tables: "users" and "expenses". 
Table USERS:
id - Primary, Auto Increment;
username
password, etc...

Table EXPENSES:
id (this is not autoincrement),
username, ammount, date reason -> other fields.

I am using a function called getuserfields() to get the fields from the USERS table(it's stored in a core.php file i have required in every php):

```
if (!function_exists('getuserfield')) {
     function getuserfield($field) {  //
        //echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
        /*$query2 = "SELECT `$field` FROM `expenses` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";*/
        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
             if($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)){ // get the result form the query, row 0 (1 row) cause that is gonna return 1 row/
                  return $query_result;
               }

          }
  }
}
```

In my index.php file I have declared variables:

```
if (loggedin()){
  $firstname =  getuserfield('firstname');
  .....
  $spent =  getuserfield('spent');      //until here they work as these are variables from users table

  $ammount =  getuserfield('ammount'); //the following are variables from expenses table, and are not working
  $date =  getuserfield('date');
  $reason =  getuserfield('reason');
  $username =  getuserfield('username');
```

I am trying to write them into the database via this function:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `expenses` VALUES (id,'".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($ammount)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($reason)."' )";
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    header ('Location: register_success.php');
    } else {
    echo 'Sorry, we couldn\'t add your expense for the moment.';
    }
```

Of course, I get the echo message from the query which is triggered when the query doesn't take place.
I am using _POST to get them from a form, which looks like this:

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
<strong>Add expense</strong> <br/>
Ammount: <br/> 
<input type="text" placeholder="Ammount" name="ammount" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['ammount'])?$_POST['ammount']:null; ?>"><br/>
Date: <br/> 
<input type="date" placeholder="Enter Date" name="date" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['date'])?$_POST['date']:null; ?>"><br/>
Reason of expense: <br/> 
<input type="text" placeholder="Reason for expense" name="reason" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['reason'])?$_POST['reason']:null; ?>"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

I am quite new so... any sugestions ? Thanks

Comment: Also, the error message "Sorry, we couldn't add your expense for the moment." pops up right when the index file loads, and should only when I click the submit button.

Comment: Do you really do a separate query for each variable? Why not do a single `select *` and then access `$row['field']`?

Comment: you are using a very bad method for getting your user data. Fetch the data once instead of running  query for each field

Comment: You need to make your `INSERT` code dependent on `isset($_POST['Submit'])`, so it only runs when you submit the form.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I put the query inside a if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {....} as you mentioned. Now, it only triggers when clicking the submit button. However, I still get the error message which probably means it's not connecting to the expense table.

Comment: Obligatory... Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use PDO or MySQLi - this article will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @lbu , can you be more specific please ? are you referring to the getuserfield() function ?

Comment: @Cataneo lbu is referring to the same thing I was -- you should get all the columns once, not do new queries for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id isn't a variable in your expenses query. You should add error messages to your queries to help you debug them in the future.

```
$query = mysql_query("
   INSERT INTO
      `expenses`
   VALUES
   (
     $id,
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($ammount)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($reason)."'
   )")
or die ('Sorry, we couldn\'t add your expense for the moment: ' . mysql_error());

header ('Location: register_success.php');
```

Also you really should be using [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [mysql is deprecated as of php 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) so you should save yourself the trouble of re-writing everything in the future.

Comment: I see, I replaced it with this, and I get the error: Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\spr\index.php on line 89
Sorry, we couldn't add your expense for the moment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'csmarand', '', '', '' )' at line 5.  Is it related to the PDO, MySQLi everyone is referring to ? Will it work if I get the login replaced ?

Comment: No it's because $id isn't defined. If it's not an auto-incrementing table then you have to assign something to the $id variable. If it is an auto-incrementing table then you don't need to pass an ID but then you'll need to specify the field list.

Comment: OK, I was lookin the PDO and found a new way to connect to my DB. At first, I was using this to connect:     < ? php
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

$mysql_db='spr'; // name of my database

if (!@mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass) || !@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
  die ('Cannot connect to database.');
}  

?>.......  Now I'm connecting like this: <?php $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=spr;charset=utf8', 'root', ''); ?> .... but I guess I still have to make a lot of changes for the code to work. How do I replace the IF statement ?